# Location popup not working after select block option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on Php and ajax, I have button and whenever we click on that button,then
"Location popup" ( allow site to access your location) showing after select "allow" code is working fine
but whenever we click on "block" then futher code is not working (function error) not working,How can i do this ?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".in").click(function () {
                const options = {
                      enableHighAccuracy: true,
                      timeout: 5000,
                      maximumAge: 0
                    };
                function success(pos) {
                      const crd = pos.coords;
                      var lats = crd.latitude;
                      var longs = crd.longitude;
                      var userId = <?php echo $ids=$_GET['eid']; ?>
                      
                       $.ajax({
                            // further code
                        });
                    }   
                    
                function error(err) {
                        var pathname = window.location.href;
                        // Now want to go futher even click on "block" button
                      }
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
            });
        }); 

<button name="intime" class="clcbtn in">Clock in</button>
```

Comment: How do you know, that the error function doesn't work? In your code you are only setting a variable in it and do nothing else.

Comment: @Geshode let me explain , error function working but i want if go to error function then ajax should work ( data should enter into db even error comes) , means "location module" should be optional , hope you understand,

Comment: But if the user denies access to the location data, then what data do you want to put into the DB? Without access rights, you can't get location data.

Comment: @Geshode you are right i cant get location data but i want to insert other data ( see // ajax further code) so in other words "location" should be optional , hope you understand my point

Comment: @Geshode Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have another ajax call in your error function, but if the first error was caused by a problem with ajax, then the second ajax call might also run into an error.

So, you should make sure, that the error was because the user declined the access adn then you can have another ajax call.

```
function error(err) {
    if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        // Put your second ajax call here
    }
}
```